# add intermediate step in mui stepper and overriding style

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I would like to change the following code to meet my needs

1. I need to change the design from this :

[image]

to this :

[image]

I can not change the style and also add an intermediate step

here is the lin to the sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalnonlinearstepper-demo-material-ui-forked-9pqxxk

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want them to be closer to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the stepper icons closer to each other simply change the `width` of your `<Stepper />` component. I chose `400px`, change this value to fit your needs.

```
sx={{
  width: "400px",
  ...
}}
```

I replaced the content `>` with a wider arrow `❯` and adjusted the `top` alignment.

```
".MuiStepConnector-root": {
  top: 2
},
".MuiStepConnector-root span::before": {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  content: '"❯"'
}
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit HorizontalNonLinearStepper demo — Material UI (forked)]